# How could I loop through a list setting a variable for each item in the list and run a source file

Tags: r

I have a list of values (one column tibble? not sure if that is also causing problems), looking to run a source script where I pass each of the items in the list one at a time and loop through it.

my list printed:

```
[1] "SF"  "ARI" "CHI" "DET" "CLE" "BAL" "LA"  "DAL" "GB"  "MIN" "HOU" "KC"  "IND" "JAX" "CIN"
[16] "LAC" "LV"  "CAR" "MIA" "NE"  "NYJ" "BUF" "WAS" "PHI" "NYG" "PIT" "ATL" "SEA" "NO"  "TB" 
[31] "TEN" "DEN"
```

Bad for loops I have tried:

```
for(i in teams){team_focus=i %>%
  source("~/Documentsteam-plots.R", echo = TRUE)

  }


for(i in teams) { 
  assign(team_focus, i)
  print(i)
}
```

the top of my source script also then will change the wd, not sure if that matters?

```
saveto <- paste("~/Documents/nfl/week 12/",team_focus,sep = "")
setwd(paste(saveto))
```

Error I get when even trying to just run the source:

```
Error in source(., "~/Documentsteam-plots.R", echo = TRUE) :
```

'local' must be TRUE, FALSE or an environment

Comment: Hello Tay. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question.

Comment: In your source file, wrap your code with `myfun <- function(team_focus) { ... }`where `...` is your existing code, and then in your executable script, run `purrr::map(mylist, myfun)` to loop through each element of your list (I'm calling `mylist` here because I don't know how you named it.)

Comment: @Phil Here is where I am stuck now, do I run that source before now going to my executable script and running the purr command?

So I wrapped the existing code that requires the `team_focus` passed and then the purr you sent changing mylist to teams (the list I made).

When running the file I put in that wrapper if I pass one of the items in the list it runs with no errors. But when trying now it shows this in the console:

Comment: Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 6 or 1, not size 32.
ℹ Input `..1` is `posteam == team_focus`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: passer = "A.Dalton", posteam = "DAL".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
In posteam == team_focus :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: It is my list now that is the problem. So when I create a list from a dataframe taking a column and parsing out the unique values it doesn't work. When I just make the list manually doing <- c() it does. 

Is there something I should do to convert a tibble with a header / column and rows to a basic list?

Comment: I just manually pasted and made my teams <- c() pasting from the output I put here hahaha. Works and running.

Comment: `c()` does not return a list, but a vector. `list()` is to be used to return a list. Either way, it's not possible to help further without a reproducible example as suggested earlier.

Comment: Yeah i just am too big of a noob to pull off a good reproducible example so your solution was enough for now. Really appreciate it @phil